# Is there any method to fetch the data from back-end MongoDB and show at front-end react JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to show my backend data from mongoDB into front-end and calculate the balance of a particular member
Here is the code:

```
export default function BuySellInfo() {
 const[xnaLogData,setXnaLogData]=useState([]);
    const [balance,setBalance]=useState(0);
  const calBal =()=>{
    var sum = xnaLogData.reduce(function(prev, current) {
      return prev + +current.balance
    }, 0);
    setBalance(sum);
  }

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchXna () {
    const response = await fetch('/xnaloginforoute');
    const json = await response.json();
    setXnaLogData(json.xnacomp);
    console.log(json.xnacomp)
    console.log(xnaLogData);
}
    fetchXna();
    calBal();
},[]);


  return (
    <div>
               <table className="table" style={{width:"30%",marginLeft:"3%"}}>
      <tbody>
    <h2 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>  Buy & Sell </h2>
        <tr>
          <td>Member No</td>
          <td>{xnaLogData[0].memberno}</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XNA Balance</td>
          <td>{balance}</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

The above component will fetch the data from the back-end route. Although the route is working fine with postman whenever i send the request but its showing error in the front-end . And the error is sometimes removed (which means data fetched perfectly) but on the first attempt the data is not fetched, after commenting or uncommenting the line of code : `{/* <td>{xnaLogData[0].memberno}</td> */}`
from above component the fetch api work. I am unable to sort out this issue.
The back-end route is :

```
router.get('/xnaloginforoute', async (req, res) => {
  const xnacomp=await xnaLog.find({})
  res.json({xnacomp});
});
```

What i had figured about this issue that response is not fetched in first attempt in front-end but through Postman it is working correctly. But i am unable to solve this issue.
And how to get the data or fetch is that:

> First click on BuySell button to open this component
> It will show error of **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memberno')** as i had not comment out the line `{ <td>{xnaLogData[0].memberno}</td> }`
> But then i comment the line `{/* <td>{xnaLogData[0].memberno}</td> */}` and the table will appear with no values as the line of code is comment out
> Then i uncomment the line `{ <td>{xnaLogData[0].memberno}</td> }` the data will be fetched perfectly and stored in usestate

I couldnt understand the things in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line under your `useEffect` and above your `return`:

```js
if (!xnaLogData.length) {
  return null;
}
```

You're fetching data for your table that's not going to be available at initial render of the component so `xnaLogData[0]` is `undefined`